# Why doesn't C# support implied generic types on class constructors?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

C# doesn't require you to specify a generic type parameter if the compiler can infer it, for instance:

```
List<int> myInts = new List<int> {0,1,1,
    2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144,233,377,
    610,987,1597,2584,4181,6765};

//this statement is clunky
List<string> myStrings = myInts.
    Select<int,string>( i => i.ToString() ).
    ToList<string>();

//the type is inferred from the lambda expression
//the compiler knows that it's taking an int and 
//returning a string
List<string> myStrings = myInts.
    Select( i => i.ToString() ).
    ToList();
```

This is needed for anonymous types where you don't know what the type parameter would be (in intellisense it shows up as `'a`) because it's added by the compiler.

Class-level type parameters don't let you do this:

```
//sample generic class
public class GenericDemo<T> 
{
    public GenericDemo ( T value ) 
    {
        GenericTypedProperty = value;
    }

    public T GenericTypedProperty {get; set;}
}

//why can't I do:
int anIntValue = 4181;
var item = new GenericDemo( anIntValue ); //type inference fails

//however I can create a wrapper like this:
public static GenericDemo<T> Create<T> ( T value )
{
    return new GenericDemo<T> ( value );
}

//then this works - type inference on the method compiles
var item = Create( anIntValue );
```

Why doesn't C# support this class level generic type inference?

Comment: Why does this question have a vote to close against it as a duplicate of [Why can't the C# constructor infer type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167) when that question is two years more recent? Surely that's the duplicate?

Comment: I think the other question is more concise, and it has a better answer.

Comment: @Sam - yes, Eric Lippert's answer to that question is authoritative, but I don't think either question should be closed.

Comment: **Update 2017**: If you'd like this feature, please vote for the proposal at https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/281

Comment: @ColonelPanic cheers, I've thumbs upped that issue, but it isn't really at a voting stage - response appears to be "there are complications, but we'd like to get to it too". I'll follow it though, thanks.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Actually, your question isn't bad. I've been toying with a generic programming language for last few years and although I've never come around to actually develop it (and probably never will), I've thought a lot about generic type inference and one of my top priorities has always been to allow the construction of classes without having to specify the generic type.

C# simply lacks the set of rules to make this possible. I think the developers never saw the neccesity to include this. Actually, the following code would be very near to your proposition and solve the problem. All C# needs is an added syntax support.

```
class Foo<T> {
    public Foo(T x) { … }
}

// Notice: non-generic class overload. Possible in C#!
class Foo {
    public static Foo<T> ctor<T>(T x) { return new Foo<T>(x); }
}

var x = Foo.ctor(42);
```

Since this code actually works, we've shown that the problem is not one of semantics but simply one of lacking support. I guess I have to take back my previous posting. ;-)

Answer (score 11):

> Why doesn't C# support this class level generic type inference?

Because they're generally ambiguous. By contrast, type inference is trivial for function calls (if all types appear in arguments). But in the case of constructor calls (glorified functions, for the sake of discussion), the compiler has to resolve multiple levels at the same time. One level is the class level and the other is the constructor arguments level. I believe solving this is algorithmically non-trivial. Intuitively, I'd say it's even NP-complete.

To illustrate an extreme case where resolution is impossible, imagine the following class and tell me what the compiler should do:

```
class Foo<T> {
    public Foo<U>(U x) { }
}

var x = new Foo(1);
```

Comment: From the way the Konrad's question is formulated I already know that the type "int" cannot simply be inferred from the "new Foo(1)"-example, but could anyone explain to me why not? I mean, if I say "var x = 1", I end up with an int, so how is that different from this example?

Comment: I don't think *Because they're generally ambiguous* is a very good reason; generic methods are ambiguous, too, in the presence of non-generic ones with the same signatures.

Comment: @Sam I totally agree, hence see my other (accepted) answer. However, I do believe that this *is* the original reason why they don’t exist in C#. This question is really old the answers are written before Stack Overflow enforced more stringent rules regarding answers, and before comments were implemented – as a consequence, this whole thread reads more than a discussion (which it was). The only reason I haven’t deleted this answer is because otherwise the rest of the answers here become even more confusing

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Konrad, that's a good response (+1), but just to expand on it.

Let's pretend that C# has an explicit constructor function:

```
//your example
var x = new Foo( 1 );

//becomes
var x = Foo.ctor( 1 );

//your problem is valid because this would be
var x = Foo<T>.ctor<int>( 1 );
//and T can't be inferred
```

You're quite right that the first constructor can't be inferred.

Now let's go back to the class

```
class Foo<T> 
{
    //<T> can't mean anything else in this context
    public Foo(T x) { }
}

//this would now throw an exception unless the
//typeparam matches the parameter
var x = Foo<int>.ctor( 1 );

//so why wouldn't this work?
var x = Foo.ctor( 1 );
```

Of course, if I add your constructor back in (with its alternate type) we have an ambiguous call - exactly as if a normal method overload couldn't be resolved.