# numpy.ndarray: converting to a "normal" class

Tags: python, numpy, python-3.x, wrapper

[Python 3]

I like `ndarray` but I find it annoying to use.

Here's one problem I face. I want to write `class Array` that will inherit much of the functionality of ndarray, but has only one way to be instantiated: as a zero-filled array of a certain size. I was hoping to write:

```
class Array(numpy.ndarray):
  def __init__(size):
    # What do here?
```

I'd like to call `super().__init__` with some parameters to create a zero-filled array, but it won't work since `ndarray` uses a global function `numpy.zeros` (rather than a constructor) to create a zero-filled array.

Questions:

1. Why does ndarray use global (module) functions instead of constructors in many cases? It is a big annoyance if I'm trying to reuse them in an object-oriented setting.
2. What's the best way to define `class Array` that I need? Should I just manually populate `ndarray` with zeroes, or is there any way to reuse the `zeros` function?

Comment: I don't see why you want to create your own class at all.  What is the advantage over the `numpy.zeros()` factory function?  If you don't like the name, just rename it, like `create_array = numpy.zeros`.

Comment: I am no longer sure there is an advantage. Maybe I am just not used to factory function. I'll have to think about it.

Comment: @Sven Marnach: I found several links on this general topic:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628950/constructors-vs-factory-methods

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2959871/factory-vs-instance-constructors

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617311/creation-of-objects-constructors-or-static-factory-methods

Nothing specific to Python, but general comments from other languages seem to apply. And as far as I can tell, there's really no disadvantage to factory functions (other than my personal preference).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't like `ndarray` interface then don't inherit it. You can define your own interface and delegate the rest to ndarray and numpy.

```
import functools
import numpy as np


class Array(object):

    def __init__(self, size):
        self._array = np.zeros(size)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try: return getattr(self._array, attr)
        except AttributeError:
            # extend interface to all functions from numpy
            f = getattr(np, attr, None)
            if hasattr(f, '__call__'):
                return functools.partial(f, self._array)
            else:
                raise AttributeError(attr)

    def allzero(self):
        return np.allclose(self._array, 0)


a = Array(10)
# ndarray doesn't have 'sometrue()' that is the same as 'any()' that it has.
assert a.sometrue() == a.any() == False
assert a.allzero()

try: a.non_existent
except AttributeError:
    pass
else:
    assert 0
```

Comment: Very neat. I assume that all `numpy` global functions have the same semantics when called with `ndarray` argument as the same-name instance method of `ndarray`.

Comment: To change to Python 3, I just remove `(object)` from the class definition, correct? [Not that leaving it would cause problems.]

Comment: @max: the code works without changes on both 2.x and Python 3.

Comment: I seem to be missing something here.  You don't derive from `ndarray`, but if any attribute is requested, you first try to get the attribute from the `ndarray` instance.  Wouldn't it be much easier to derive from `ndarray` in the first place?  You still can add the magic to add the module level functions in numpy as methods, but I don't think this is a  good idea either, because most of them **are** already methods, and the rest does not make sense as a method (with very few exceptions).

Comment: @Sven Marnach: The premise is that the OP finds `ndarray` annoying to use. Delegation is a more flexible approach to change class interface than inheritance. The code is not a final solution but it is just a mere skeleton example that allows to extend it to use black-, white- list approaches, etc. I agree about module level functions. The code shows *how* you can do it; it doesn't advocate that it is a sensible thing to do.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for the clarification -- I completely agree.

Answer (score 9):

> Why does ndarray use global (module) functions instead of constructors in many cases?

1. To be compatible/similar to Matlab, where functions like `zeros` or `ones` originally came from.
2. Global factory functions are quick to write and easy to understand. What should the semantics of a constructor be, e.g. how would you express a simple `zeros` or `empty` or `ones` with one single constructor? In fact, such factory functions are quite common, also in other programming languages.

> What's the best way to define `class Array` that I need?

```
import numpy

class Array(numpy.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls, size):
        result = numpy.ndarray.__new__(Array, size)
        result.fill(0)
        return result
arr = Array(5)

def test(a):
    print type(a), a

test(arr)
test(arr[2:4])
test(arr.view(int))

arr[2:4] = 5.5

test(arr)
test(arr[2:4])
test(arr.view(int))
```

Note that this is Python 2, but it would require only small modifications to work with Python 3.

Comment: Some remarks: 1. The `shape` parameter to the `ndarray` constructor may simply be an integer instead of a tuple.  2. `dtype=float` is the default.  3. In Python 3, you can omit the arguments to `super()` in this case.  Combining these remarks, the first two lines of the constructor reduce to `super().__init__(size)`.

Comment: Oh, and I just notice that your `super()` call is wrong -- should be `super(Array, self)` in Python 2.x.

Comment: You're right, I've edited my answer. (The constructor signature is undocumented, as usual.)

Comment: @Philipp: It's documented in the docstring of the class, not of the constructor itself.  But this is actually where the doc belongs.

Comment: @Sven: What I mean is that the doc says `shape` has to be a tuple, and doesn't say `dtype` defaults to `float`.

Comment: @Philipp: My docstring *does* give me the default value for `dtype`. (Maybe different version?)  And a shape can *always* be a tuple or an integer, but the doc indeed says "tuple of ints" in this case.

Comment: @Sven: Indeed I missed the `dtype=float` declaration. Regarding `shape`, I was puzzled because the last example uses a one-element tuple instead of an integer.

Comment: @Philipp: it won't work, since there is no `__init__` method in `ndarray`. I know that in Python 3, it attempts to call `object.__init__` (and fails because of the wrong number of parameters). Thank you for the comments about the `zeros` though - it helps me understand where it came from.

Comment: @max: It *does* work, I've tested it, no need to downvote! The call to the non-existing `ndarray` constructor is wrong and I've removed it. The array is correctly initialized by the `__new__` method.

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance of ndarray is little bit tricky. `ndarray` does not even have method `__init(self, )___`, so it can't be called from subclass, but there are reasons for that. Please see numpy documentation of [subclassing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.subclassing.html).

By the way could you be more specific of your particular needs? It's still quite easy to cook up a class (utilizing ndarray) for your own needs, but a subclass of ndarray to pass all the numpy machinery is quite different issue.

*It seems that I can't comment my own post, odd*
@Philipp: It will be called by Python, but not by numpy. There are three ways to instantiate ndarray, and the guidelines how to handle all cases is given on that doc.

Comment: I seem to have missed this document. But why is the `__init__` method in my example called even though `ndarray` had `__new__`?

Comment: @Philipp: see my comment to your answer.

Comment: I just wanted my own class that I fully control how it's instantiated. You're right subclassing ndarray is too hard. I'll follow the container approach in @J.F. Sebastian.