# Type inference fails mysteriously

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

Why does the following fail to infer `R`:

```
static R Foo<R>(Func<Action<R>, R> call) { ... }
```

While pretty much the 'same', works:

```
static R Foo<R>(Func<Action, R> call) { ... }
```

Usage:

```
var i = Foo(ec => -1);
```

Ways the first sample 'must' be called to compile:

```
var i = Foo<int>(ec => -1);
```

-- or --

```
var i = Foo((Action<int> ec) => -1);
```

Thoughts: As can be seen in the second snippet, `R` is already determined by the return type of the 'lambda'. Why can't the same apply to the first? Even with usage of `ec` (which should be another compiler hint), it fails to infer.

Comment: So, in your example, `ec` is convertible to a delegate that takes an `int` and returns `void`?

Comment: The type inference rules in C# are made to cover the basic cases. There are some rare cases where the rules (intentionally) don't "take".

Comment: Can you add an example declaration/implementation of `ec`?  My guess is that the problem lies there.

Comment: Here's an interesting article on the subject. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/jj131514.aspx. May or may not actually answer your question, but good background info.

Comment: @ChrisShain: Full example code: https://gist.github.com/2868328

Comment: @SirPentor: Thanks. Edit: Does not cover the issue.

Comment: I may have found your duplicate ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229131/why-cant-c-sharp-infer-type-from-this-seemingly-simple-obvious-case

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: Thanks, almost the same, will read a bit more to see if the same applies :)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus: I think it is the same issue, except that I am experiencing it in a 'nested' environment. The answer given provides an acceptable understanding. Feel free to 'Mark as duplicate' though :)

Comment: @Ieppie nono, I like "mysterious" titles ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the problem is not that the compiler if failing to infer `R` for the function `CallWithEscapeContinuation`, it is that it is failing to infer a type for the lambda:

```
ec =>
{
  Enumerable.Range(0, 100).Select(x =>
  {
              // Called here, the compiler has no idea what signature to expect for `ec`
              // Could be Action<Int>, could be Action<Decimal> (for example).
    if (x == 40) ec(x);
    return x;
  }).ToList();
  return -1;
}
```

Whereas when you provide the `int` hint, it can infer what type the lambda is from that and the signature of `CallWithEscapeContinuation`.

When you just have `Action` (as opposed to `Action<R>`) the above is irrelevant because there are no type parameters affecting the possible signatures of the lambda.

Comment: Range returns `IEnumerable<int>`, why would `x` be anything else than an `int`?

Comment: If you comment out everything and just return -1 it doesn't infer the return type either.

Comment: It will fail on this too: `var index = CallWithEscapeContinuation(ec => { ec(1); return -1; });`

Comment: @Slugart that's because it still doesn't know what `ec` is.

Comment: @ChrisShain: I disagree, it knows exactly what `ec` is. It does not have much of a choice at this point!

Comment: @leppie again, in the comment example, the compiler doesn't know what signature the lambda has because it doesn't know the signature of `ec`.  Edit: for instance, it could (again) be `Action<Decimal>`.  For instance:  `var index = CallWithEscapeContinuation((Action<Decimal> ec) => { ec(1); return -1; });`

Comment: @ChrisShain: That last example made sense :)

Comment: The compiler knows x is an int at that line so it should be able to infer that the first param to ec is an int.  To take away the implicit conversions, what if the delegate body were { ec(""); return ""; } ?

Comment: BTW, I am not entirely convinced the compiler cannot figure these things out. Eg `Foo<int>(ec => { ec("1"); return "2";})` fails to compile.

Comment: @Slugart the compiler knows that you are *calling* `ec` with an argument of type `int`, but that doesn't mean that `ec`'s signature is `Action<int>`.  A variety of other signatures would work too, but may require type casting.

Comment: @leppie that fails to compile for a different reason- it groks the lambda, but then the type of the lambda's first parameter (`Action<String>`) conflicts with `Foo<int>`