# Why can these type arguments not be inferred when passing named methods?

Tags: c#, generics, delegates, type-inference

In the below code block, I've numbered four lines within Main.  Here are my questions/comments on them:

1. Will not compile because Squared is not a Func<T, R> (expected).
2. Will compile because squared is a Func<T, R> (expected).
3. Produces the following compiler error:

   > The type arguments for method 'ConsoleApplication1.FunctionExt.DelegateOf<T,R>(System.Func<T,R>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
4. Produces the same kind of error:

   > The type arguments for method 'ConsoleApplication1.FunctionExt.ForwardCompose<T1,T2,R>(System.Func<T1,T2>, System.Func<T2,R>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

I'd appreciate an explanation for why the errors in 3 and 4 occur.

```
public static class FunctionExt
{
    public static Func<T, R> DelegateOf<T, R>(Func<T, R> func)
    {
        return func;
    }

    public static Func<T1, R> ForwardCompose<T1, T2, R>(this Func<T1, T2> func1, Func<T2, R> func2)
    {
        return x => func2(func1(x));
    }
}

public class Program
{
    static int Squared(int n)
    {
        return n * n;
    }

    static int Plus5(int n)
    {
        return n + 5;
    }

    static Func<int, int> squared = Squared;

    public static void Main()
    {
        // 1
        Squared.ForwardCompose(Plus5);

        // 2
        squared.ForwardCompose(Plus5);

        // 3
        FunctionExt.DelegateOf(Squared).ForwardCompose(Plus5);

        // 4
        FunctionExt.ForwardCompose(Squared, Plus5);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have just added the generic types to the line 3 and 4 and it is compling I hope will this solve your problem.

Comment: Explicitly providing the type arguments will of course allow it to compile, but the question is why the type arguments cannot be inferred.

Comment: What version of C# are you using?

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is that generic arg type inference stumbles because `Squared` is a method group (in contrast to `squared` which is a delegate) and as such does not have a fixed signature to help with inference.

Comment: @Servy: I thought about it a little more. In this case that's true, but in the general case the problem still exists. Replaced that comment with the above.

Comment: @Jon Yes, clearly the difference here is between a delegate and a method group.  In this case though the method group is of size one, so *technically* the type could be inferred, although the C# compiler doesn't do so.  I just don't understand the type inference rules thoroughly enough to explain why it doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't C# infer type from this seemingly simple, obvious case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229131/why-cant-c-sharp-infer-type-from-this-seemingly-simple-obvious-case)

Comment: So it treats it as a method group even when there aren't any overloads?  I suppose it makes sense that it would have to just in case an overload is added later on...

Comment: In trying to find an answer for this, I found this discussion [thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2a73744b-9319-4c48-ac98-9709bcb4aeb5/type-inference-method-group-arguments?forum=csharplanguage) which was enlightening

Comment: to simplfiy the problem you can change: DelegateOf<T>(Action<T> squared)  FunctionExt.DelegateOf<int>(Squared); the generic definition need the type!

Comment: @User3805967 As has already been said to you, the question is why type inference fails, not how to get it to compile without type inference.

Comment: @Servy then it is really duplicate of link which Jeffery and ledbutter have post it.

Comment: @User3805967 the link I shared was to an MSDN discussion, not SO

Comment: In the first, third and fourth you made a Typo by typing Squared with a capital S :)

Answer (score 0):

This compiles:

```
    // 1
    squared.ForwardCompose(Plus5);

    // 2
    squared.ForwardCompose(Plus5);

    // 3
    FunctionExt.DelegateOf(squared).ForwardCompose(Plus5);

    // 4
    FunctionExt.ForwardCompose(squared, Plus5);
```