# Nested Func cannot be inferred from usage

Tags: c#, generics, inferred-type

**Q: Why can the generic arguments to Inferred not be inferred?**

When looking at the example below the type `T` can be inferred as `Instance` and we can see that we need that method with no arguments which is also supplied. That method returns an `TOut` which must be an `int` since we cannot have overloads on return types.

```
public class Instance
{
    public int Convert()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

public static class Example
{
    public static void Inferred<T, TOut>(T source, Expression<Func<T, Func<TOut>>> expression)
    {
    }

    public static void Usage()
    {
        var instance = new Instance();
        Inferred(instance, x => x.Convert);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess because enabling the compiler to infer this would be too much work for too little benefit. Note that in case a reference type is returned inference would not really be possible -- if `Convert` returns `string`, is `TOut` `string` or `object`?

Comment: See this answer. The seminal text on the subject! Http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203643/generic-methods-in-net-cannot-have-their-return-types-inferred-why

Comment: Found the correct answer here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6229131/why-cant-c-sharp-infer-type-from-this-seemingly-simple-obvious-case/6231921#6231921