# Pass List<anonymous type> into method requiring List<T> in C#

Tags: c#, generics

Is this possible?

```
var cats = catsource.Select(c => new
{
    CatId = c.catId,
    Name = c.Name,
}).ToList();
```

`var myCatObject = new CatData(cats);`

This doesn't work because the compiler says it can't convert `cats` into `List<T>`.

`cats` is an anonymous type, and `CatData` is:

```
public class CatData<T>
{
    public int total;
    public int records;
    public List<T> records;

    public CatData(List<T> dataObjects, int totalRecords, int numberOfRows)
    {
        total = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecords / numberOfRows);
        records = totalRecords;
        rows = dataObjects;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

---

Edit:

So I have done this code, but there is still a problem:

```
 public class CatData
 {
     public int total;
     public int records;
     public List<T> rows;

     private CatData(List<T> dataObjects, int totalRecords, int numberOfRows)
     {
         total = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecords / numberOfRows);
         records = totalRecords;
         rows = dataObjects;
     }

     public static CatData<T> Create(List<T> dataObjects, int totalRecords, int numberOfRows)
     {
         return new CatData<T>(dataObjects, totalRecords, numberOfRows);
     }
 }
```

This code has an error on every instance of `<T>` saying

> Cannot resolve symbol T

If I alter the class to be `public class CatData<T>` it compiles, but then I cannot have this code:

`CatData.Create(records, totalRecords, rows);`

Because it says

> incorrect number of type parameters.

---

Update to explain what I want:

I want to create a list of objects which have an anonymous type

`var someList = someCollection.Select(new { ... });`

I want to create an object which stores them as a `List<anonymous>`

`var myObject = new myObject(someList, 5);`

So I can do:

`myObject.someValue; // 5 (stored it in the constructor)`
`myObject.myList.Count(); // can count how many anonymous objects are in there`

Perhaps I should just store it as a `List<object>`.

---

I don't really get it, maybe I'm just a bit too thick. I've just ended up with this:

`public CatData(List<object> dataObjects, int totalRecords, int numberOfRows)` as my constructor.

`var catData = new CatData(records.Cast<object>().ToList(), totalRecords, rows);`

Comment: What is `CatData` post its definition

Comment: And what is `T` in the CatData constructor?

Comment: Ever since when does constructors allows generic parameters?!

Comment: There is no `T` since the code is calling the constructor, so it should be the type of `cats`

Comment: Where does `T` come from when you're constructing `CatData`? Is it actually supposed to be `new CatData<T>(cats)`? If so, then you can't do it this way, instead create a factory method where `T` can be inferred.

Comment: Forget about anonymous type. Can you compile this without that? **no**! Where does that `T` came from?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your comment. I have an anonymous collection, `List<'a>` and I want to create an object and pass that in and store it. That's all I want to do.

Comment: You should understand that you can't have a `public List<T> rows;` (generic field) in a non generic class.

Comment: So why can't I make the class generic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to define a factory method.

Generics are inferred (if possible) when calling methods, but not when calling constructors.

So add this:

```
public static class CatData
{
    public static CatData<T> Create<T>(List<T> cats)
    {
        return new CatData<T>(cats);
    }
}
```

used like this:

```
var data = CatData.Create(cats);
```

Eric Lippert has also provided an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type/3570360#3570360) talking about some of the considerations for why this is not allowed.

With the introduction of the new [Roslyn compiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/roslyn.aspx), new features might have a better chance of appearing as it would mean that 1 change can apply to multiple languages and would be easier to implement, which is probably what sparked new life into this discussion, as [apparently supporting type inference on generic constructor parameters is now being considered: DamienG's blog, Probable C# 6.0 features illustrated](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated)

---

Since there seems to be some confusion as whether this trick actually works or not, here's a complete [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    var test = new[]
    {
        new { name = "Test", id = 42 },
        new { name = "Test 2", id = 17 }
    }.ToList();
    CatData.Create(test);
}

public class CatData<T>
{
    public CatData(List<T> list)
    {
    }
}

public static class CatData
{
    public static CatData<T> Create<T>(List<T> list)
    {
        return new CatData<T>(list);
    }
}
```

This works just fine, illustrating that it is entirely legal to have both the static non-generic class and the generic class with the same class name, in the same namespace and assembly.

There should be ample evidence of this in the .NET framework as well, since Tuple exists with multiple versions.

Comment: That has solved the issue. Seems a bit strange why it doesn't work for the constructor but I am sure there is a clever reason

Comment: actually may have spoken too soon, without defining the class as `CatData<T>` it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: See [Eric Lipperts answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type/3570360#3570360).

Comment: It does work as stated, if it doesn't for you then you need to show your code as I know this "trick" works.

Comment: Also note that they are apparently considering changing this to be supported, inferring generic types in the constructor. See [Probably C# 6.0 Features Illustrated](http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated) for examples.

Comment: I get `class CatData does not have type parameters` unless I put `<T>` on the class definition. But if I do that, I can no longer call it without specifying the type, and there is no type.

Comment: Can you please provide a short and complete program that illustrates the problem now as this works just fine, so there must be something else wrong in this case.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen It seems OP doesn't want `CatData` to be generic. It is not clear how he's expecting it to work without generic when he have `List<T> dataObjects` as parameter

Comment: Note that you need to create a separate static non-generic class for the factory method. You can't put the static method inside the existing generic class.

Comment: Why not? It's static so it shouldn't interfere? Or am i missing something?

Comment: You're missing the point that in order for you to *use* the generic type, you *have to specify the generic type arguments*. Since you can't do that here, you need to use this trick to get to the situation where the compiler *will* infer the types, which is when calling generic *methods*. However, if you place that method in the generic class, you're back to square one. Having the static class with the generic *method* lets the compiler infer the generic types for you. There's no way around this.

Comment: The code above seems to have worked by separating it into a different class. I will try to see if I can understand it but I am a not very good at understanding generics. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Generic type inference works when you call methods, so you should create a factory method:

```
public static class CatData
{
    public static CatData<T> Create<T>(List<T> dataObjects, int totalRecords, int numberOfRows)
    {
        return new CatData<T>(dataObjects, totalRecords, numberOfRows);
    }
}
```

and now you can do:

```
var cats = catsource.Select(c => new
{
    CatId = c.catId,
    Name = c.Name,
}).ToList();

var myCatObject = CatData.Create(cats, cats.Length, cats.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make a constructor generic; and to instantiate a generic class you need to specify the class parameters.

But, there's a work-around:

```
public static class CatDataHelper
{
    public static CatData<T> MakeCatData<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        return new CatData<T>(list);
    }
}

//...
var myCatObject = cats.MakeCatData();
```

Answer (score -4):

Instead of using var use  dynamic.

```
 dynamic cats = catsource.Select(c => new
 {
     CatId = c.catId,
      Name = c.Name,
 }).ToList();
```