# Collection Inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, collections

I am trying to achieve the following, however I am not sure if it is even possible.

I have the following 'base' entities

```
public abstract class BaseObject {}
public abstract class BaseCollection <T> : ObservableCollection<T> where T : BaseObject {}
```

I also have

```
public class Obj_1: BaseObject {}
public class Obj_1_collection : BaseCollection <Obj_1>
{
    public Obj_1_Method_1 () {}
}
```

and

```
public class Obj_2: Obj_1 {}
```

Following the same logic as `Obj_1`, I want to have a `Obj_2_collection`. I want this collection to inherit from `Obj_1_collection` in order to access its methods e.g. `Obj_2_collection.Obj_1_Method_1()`. As I have it in my mind I am trying to do something like the following (in pseudocode):

```
public class Obj_2_collection : Obj_1_collection<Obj_2 extends Obj_1>
```

meaning that the `Obj_2_collection` can access `Obj_1_collection`, however the collection object it will be of type `Obj_2`

Comment: Did you try to define your `Obj_1_collection` as `public class Obj_1_collection<T> : BaseCollection <T> where T : Obj_1 {}`

Comment: Obj_1 and Obj_2 need to inherit the same base class BaseObject.  In your code you have Obj_2 inheriting Obj_1.

Comment: @jdweng which means `Obj_2` also inherit from `BaseObject`

Comment: @jdweng This is because I need Obj_2 inheriting Obj_1, that is a part of my logic. e.g base = vehicle, Obj_1 = car, Obj_2 = luxury car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there, your only problem is that you didn't define your `Obj_1_collection` as a generic.

To do so, you just have to use the syntax you used for the `BaseCollection<T>` and restrict the type T to `Obj_1`

That would give :

```
public class Obj_1_collection<T> : BaseCollection <T> where T : Obj_1 {}
```

Concerning the use of generics and the inheritance, you might want to read about the [in](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) and [out](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) modifiers keyword to enable [covariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) and [contravariance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx).

As a side note, here are the [C# naming conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: After some quick testing your suggestion seem to work. I need to test it in a 'real world' example before accepting, but I am positive you will get the 'Check Mark'. For now +1 for the linked resources. And a disclaimer, I am familiar with the naming conventions, the naming and the code is just for example purposes.

Comment: @Athafoud That's all good then :) Better to have them linked when they are not useful than not link them while they are needed :p

Comment: The only issue I can see is that every time I am using `Obj_1_collection`, I need to instantiate it as `new Obj_1_collection<Obj_1>()`. This means a lot of refactoring, which is something I am trying to avoid.

Comment: @Athafoud It seems it is not possible to make C# infer the parameter type from the constructor, refer to this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type for more informations. Sorry it seems you won't be able to do without refactoring one way or the other.

Comment: While this is not the best approach, I am considering to duplicate the needed method(s) in both collections. At least for now coping and maintaining duplicate code, is 'less work' than the refactoring.