# Why do I need to explicitly define the generic argument's generic type on a generic class?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

Consider the following scenario:

```
public interface IEntity<TKey>
{
    TKey { get; set; }
}

public interface IRepository<TEntity, TKey>
      where TEntity : IEntity<TKey>
{
    void Store(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(TKey key);
}
```

Why do I need to expliclty add `TKey` as a generic argument to `IRepository` ?

Can't the compiler deduce or infer it from `TEntity`'s type?

I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : IEntity<TKey>
{
     void Store(TEntity entity);
     void Delete(TKey key);
}
```

It's not like `TKey` is only known at runtime:

```
IRepository<User> userRepo = new ConcreteRepository<User>();
```

Where `User` implements `IEntity<string>`

Comment: The compiler follows a specification. The specification requires the type parameter and it arguably does this for good reason as it avoids ambiguity and extra/complicated rules: consider `IEnumerable` and `IEnumerable<T>` which are both separate types. The end of the question is confusing as TKey is the name given to a type-domain restriction, separate from the 'runtime' ..

Comment: It's not relevant whether the compiler could or couldn't infer it - it doesn't, and that's it. It's annoying, yes, but that's just the way it is. The CLR spec requires every generic type argument to be defined. F# has much better type inference than C#, and it still must do this (the main difference is that it will infer the correct type when you call a method that just takes `TEntity` :)).

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
where TEntity : IEntity<TKey> {
   void Store(TEntity entity);
   void Delete(TKey key);
}
```

`TKey` is an undefined type parameter. You could say `where TEntity : IEntity<string>`, since `string` is a defined type. But if you're going to use a type parameter, you'll need to define it first.

Notice that the compiler has no idea what `TKey` is here. Is it a type? Is it a generic type parameter?

You might be able to do something like this, but it would no longer be strongly typed on `TEntity`. That may or may not be acceptable:

```
public interface IRepository<TKey> {
   void Store(IEntity<TKey> entity);
   void Delete(TKey key);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because the C# spec requires that for constructor parameters.  The canonical answer on this matter is here [Why can't the C# constructor infer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type/#3570360)

Worth noting is a couple of things: we almost got it in C#6.  You can hack around it by using a Static method that simply calls your constructor.  For instance

```
public class Entity<TKey>
{
    public Entity(TKey k)
    {

    }

}

public static class Entity
{
    public static Entity<MyKey> Create<MyKey>(MyKey mk)
    {
        return new Entity<MyKey>(mk);
    }
}
```

I placed it on a non-generic type of the same name for convenience sake.