# Create instance of object with Generics

Tags: c#

I have the following:

```
public class Query : IAsyncRequest<Envelope<Reply>> { }

public class Reply { }

public class Flow<TQuery, TReply> where TQuery: IAsyncRequest<Envelope<TReply>>, IRequest<Envelope<TReply>> {

  public TQuery Query { get; set; }
  public TReply Reply { get; set; }

  public Flow(TQuery query, TReply reply) {
    Query = query;
    Reply = reply;
  }
}
```

When I try to create an instance of Flow as

```
Query query = service.GetQuery();
Reply reply = service.GetReply();
Flow flow = new Flow(query, reply);
```

I get the error:

```
Using the generic type 'Flow<TQuery, TReply>' requires 2 type arguments
```

Can't I create a Flow this way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3570360/1625737

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't the C# constructor infer type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type)

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, as said in [@NineBerry's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39944682/4925216), the syntax `new type` must be the "real" type with mandatory generics arguments so you must write :

```
Flow<Query, Reply> flow = new Flow<Query, Reply> (query, reply);
```

That said, that constraint doesn't apply to a method, so you *could* write a static method to do the job :

```
static class Flow // not generic (same name isn't mandatory)
{
    public static Flow<TQuery, TReply> Create (TQuery query, TReply, reply) where /* constraint */
    {
        return new Flow<TQuery, TReply> (query, reply);
    }
}

// usage
Flow<Query, Reply> flow = Flow.Create (query, reply);
// or with var
var flow = Flow.Create (query, reply);
```

Comment: Ah, Factory pattern to the rescue :) ... nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the types explicitly. Type inference is not supported here. See also [Why can't the C# constructor infer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type/3570360#3570360)

```
Query query = service.GetQuery();
Reply reply = service.GetReply();
var flow = new Flow<Query, Reply>(query, reply);
```

Comment: you forgot generic arguments on the first Flow (flow's type) ;)

Comment: @Sehnsucht Thanks. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

No, you have to define the types you want to use:

```
Flow<Query, Reply> flow = new Flow<Query, Reply>(query, reply);
```

C# constructors do not support type inference.

Comment: you forgot generic arguments on the first Flow (flow's type) ;)

Comment: Thanks :) ... I fixed that.