# ASMX Web Service: How to throw soap exception from asmx service which i like to capture from client side

Tags: c#, asmx, soapexception, soap-extension

I want if client send wrong credentials then service throw soap exception but I tried but still no luck.

see my updated code from here https://github.com/karlosRivera/EncryptDecryptASMX

Anyone can download my code and run in their PC to capture the problem.

### see this area

```
[AuthExtension]
[SoapHeader("CredentialsAuth", Required = true)]
[WebMethod]
public string Add(int x, int y)
{
    string strValue = "";
    if (CredentialsAuth.UserName == "Test" && CredentialsAuth.Password == "Test")
    {
        strValue = (x + y).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        throw new SoapException("Unauthorized", SoapException.ClientFaultCode);

    }
    return strValue;
}
```

For this line `throw new SoapException("Unauthorized", SoapException.ClientFaultCode);`

The response XML body is not getting change which I have seen from my soapextension process message function.

So I have two issues now

1) I want `throw SoapException` from service for which soap response need to be changed.

2) From client side I need to catch the `SoapException`

Please view my latest code from the link and tell me what to change. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to avoid sending `SoapException`s, but more complex objects that embed error semantics. E.g.

```
[Serializable]
class Result<T>
{
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}
```

In this case your method could look like this:

```
[AuthExtension]
[SoapHeader("CredentialsAuth", Required = true)]
[WebMethod]
public Result<string> Add(int x, int y)
{
    string strValue = "";
    if (CredentialsAuth.UserName == "Test" && CredentialsAuth.Password == "Test")
    {
        return new Result<string> { Value = (x + y).ToString() };
    }
    else
    {
        return new Result<string> { IsError = true, ErrorMessage = $"Unauthorized -  {SoapException.ClientFaultCode}" };
    }
}
```

`Result` can be developed to include an array of field/input errors to return more precise error messages related to incorrect input parameter values.

Comment: Why u use Result<T> and sending and Result<string> { Value = (x + y).ToString() }; can't we write code like return new Result { Value = (x + y).ToString() }; ?

Comment: happy new year :)

Comment: No, the type must be provided in this context. If `Result<T> ` had a constructor taking a T parameter (`Result<T>(T initialValue)`), your simplification would have been possible through type inference.

Comment: sorry this is not clear why Result class has to be generic type ?

Comment: u said `your simplification would have been possible through type inference.` would u show me how simplification can be possible ? would u post some sample code if u can manage time. thanks

Comment: Generics allow to work with actual types, thus the advantage of compile time errors instead of run-time ones in some cases. I have just tested and constructors do not infer type (my bad). This is fully explained by Eric Lippert [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type).

Comment: is it not possible to work without generic for returning soap exception?

Comment: Yes, just cut the generic and use either `string Value` or `object Value` if this is supposed to work for other types, as well.

Comment: if i cut the generic then result class would look like

`[Serializable]
class Result
{
    public bool IsError { get; set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public T Value { get; set; }
}`

so return type will be as below

`return new Result { IsError = true, ErrorMessage = $"Unauthorized -  {SoapException.ClientFaultCode}" };`

does the above code will work if we cut the generic. let me know your suggestion. thanks

Comment: if i miss understand what u try to say then please explain your point in more details.

Comment: It should work. You should have `string Value` instead of `T Value` in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Consider migrate and using WCF. It was WCF Faults.

You can replace the error messages or handle erros using `SoapExtensions.AfterSerialize` or `BeforeSerialze` methods.

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7w06t139(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: would u post any sample code to return error message to client using `soapExtensions.AfterSerialize or BeforeSerialze methods. ` please come up with solution. thanks and happy new year :)

Comment: Here: `public override void ProcessMessage(SoapMessage message) {   if (message.Exception != null && message.Stage == SoapMessageStage.BeforeSerialize)
     {
  if (message.Action.EndsWith("YourAction", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && message.Exception.InnerException is InvalidOperationException)
{ if (message.Exception.InnerException.InnerException is FormatException) { var ne = new SoapException("Custom Error Message", message.Exception.Code, message.Exception.InnerException);                         message.Exception = ne;  } }`