# For which reason compiler can't infer generic class constructor type?

Tags: c#, generics

I have generic class

```
public class Foo<T> 
{
    public Foo(T data) {}
}
```

And generic static method

```
public static class Utils
{
    public static void Foo<T>(T data) {}
}
```

I wondering why this not work

```
Bar b = new Bar();

Utils.Foo<Bar>(b); 
Utils.Foo(b);      

new Foo<Bar>(b);   
new Foo(b); // compiler can't infer type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last example won't work because there is no implicit type inference for constructors in `C#`.

Comment: He knows that I suspect, it's just why can't it "implicitly" know what type to use?

Comment: You are answering with the OP question. He asks why the last line won't compiles while the second (with no type given) compiles.

Comment: If more precisely, why this is not implemented yet in C#, for what reasons

Comment: @kogoia I didn't notice this question was a duplicate, hence I answered it but it seems there is already an answer here [Why can't the C# constructor infer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type)