# Difference between Task.FromResult<TResult> vs Task.FromResult?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

Consider the following method:

(minimum working example - I am aware of it being effectively synchronous)

```
public static Task<List<int>> GetAll()
{
    var ints = new List<int>();
    ints.Add(1);
    ints.Add(2);
    ints.Add(3);

    return Task.FromResult(ints);
    // return Task<List<int>>.FromResult(ints); <-- what's the difference between this and the line before it?
}
```

I can use both ways, returning with `Task.FromResult` or `Task.FromResult<TResult>`. What is the difference between them? When would I use which? Why are there two possibilities that lead to the likely same result?

**Update:**
As they are both the same - any examples where the explicitely typed one would be required?

Comment: The first one is implicitly typed, the second one is explicitly typed.

Comment: With `Task.FromResult(ints)`, `TResult` is inferred from the type of `ints` by the compiler. With `Task.FromResult<List<int>>(ints)`, you've explicitly provided a type value for `TResult`, meaning that *only* `List<int>` can be accepted as a parameter. In terms of compiler output, they are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. I added a further question to the initial one, please see above.

Comment: re: the edit - if you wanted your result to be `short` or `long` for example, you'd have to be explicit as the automatic inference will be `int` only.

Comment: See [Why can't the C# constructor infer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type), and especially Eric Lippert's comments for cases where the C# compiler can't infer the types involved.

Comment: @stefan.at.wpf if `GetAll` returned an `Task<IEnumerable<int>>` it would not compile like this. But if you changed it to `return Task.FromResult<IEnumerable<int>>(ints);` then it would work. So there are cases where the compiler is not able to make everything work together with implicit typing.