# Invoke function on an object of unknown type

Tags: .net

Is it possible in .NET, to invoke a method/function on an object and get back it's return value without knowing the type of the object?

All the examples I could find so far use reflection and need to know the type of the object to get it's method list to invoke them.

In short, I want to invoke a method of a given name and with given parameters on any object, and get back the return value, in case this method really exists.

*For example:* Let's say I have a library X.dll with a class Y and a function Z inside it. Function Z takes two string parameters and returns a string.
I have another library A.dll, which is **NOT** referencing X.dll. A.dll has a function B somewhere inside it, which takes an object of type Y as a parameter, but since there's no referencing, this parameter is declared as `object`. Inside this function B I need to invoke function Z and do something with it's return value.

Comment: If the method name and signature is known in advance: `dynamic`; otherwise, reflection throughput; `obj.GetType().GetMethod(...)` etc and invoke - should work fine; do you have a dummy example that *isn't* working how you'd expect?

Comment: No, I'm inside a giant project and just wanted to figure out a way to do some new requirement. If this GetType().GetMethod().Invoke is working without a reference to the other DLL, I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, C# does not support class level generic type inference. There were many occasions which I wished to use reflection with the same purpose you described. It seems the feature's outweghts its costs. There is a throughout discussion about this theme here:

[Why can't the C# constructor infer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type)

Comment: This question isn't about constructing types. Other than constructing types, though, C# does a lot of type inference. Your first sentence is wrong unless you explicitly state you are talking about constructor type inference.

Comment: @Enigmativity You are right, I was not specific enough. Now I edited my answer with "Unfortunately, C# does not support class level generic type inference". Thanks.