# Why sometime I need to explicitly specific the generic type when calling constructor/function in C#?

Tags: c#, generics, types, typing, strong-typing

[image]

Refer to the image above, we can see the `AbpAsyncDeterminiationInterceptor` must have a generic type which is the same as what is provided into its constructor. Supposed it should be interpreted automatically instead of explicitly specifies something like `new AbpAsyncDeterminiationInterceptor<BlueprintInterceptor>(new BlueprintInterceptor());`

The weird point is that, sometimes when I call a function, I won't need to specify the generic type and the function could reveal the return type from the parameter type.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See [why can't the C# constructor infer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-sharp-constructor-infer-type).

Comment: In general C# compiler can infer type only in "simple" scenarios - if method is generic and has parameters for every generic parameter (and the class itself is not generic).