# Troubleshooting: Why doesn't type inference fail here?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0, type-inference

Given a type declared as shown below

```
public class EqualityProbe<T>
{
  public EqualityProbe( Func<T> functionToGetActualValue, T expectedValue, string probeDescription) {..}
```

Client code:

```
// cannot infer bool here
new EqualityProbe(CanConnectToMachine, true, "Probe machine is online")
// compiles fine
new EqualityProbe<bool>(CanConnectToMachine, true, "Probe machine is online")
```

My understanding is that type-inference doesn't work for method groups (e.g. CanConnectToMachine) or anonymous methods (lambda expressions).
But in this case, why doesn't the compiler infer the type argument from the second argument

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why can't the C# constructor infer type?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-constructor-infer-type)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why doesn't C# support implied generic types on class constructors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604/why-doesnt-c-sharp-support-implied-generic-types-on-class-constructors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C# doesn't support type inference on constructors, although this can often be overcome through the use of a factory class.

See the answer here: [Why can't the C# constructor infer type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570167/why-cant-the-c-constructor-infer-type)

Answer (score 1):

Well, that how C# is ! It doenst infer for constructors. While instantiating a generic type, you need to specify the Type(s) that will be used for the generic ones.