# C# Generic Type Inference... anyway to automatically infer the type of array elements?

Tags: c#, generics, type-inference

I'm building a MVC core IHtmlHelper extension to handle tables. Roughly speaking you provide the extension with an IEnumerable list of data records and a column layout and it produces an HTML table.

For the column layout I'd like some of the methods to be lambdas that accept a data record and return a value from it. For example for each row of the table the first column should contain such and such value from the data record.

So the MVC IHtmlHelper extension method will look like:

```
namespace TableStuff
{
    public class Column<T>
    {
        public Func<T, string> TDContent { get; set; }
        // ... plus any other settings needed
    }

    public static class Table
    {
        public static IHtmlContent BasicTable<T>(
            this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper,
            IEnumerable<T> Data,
            IEnumerable<Column<T>> Columns
            )
        {
            return new HtmlString("just a mockup");
        }       
    }
}
```

To use it you:

```
public class Test
{
    class ListEntry
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public void DefineTable()
    {
        // fake a couple of things to make example minimal
        IHtmlHelper t = null;
        var Data = new List<ListEntry>();

        // generate the table; in reality this would be a razor page via @Html.BasicTable(...)
        var c = t.BasicTable(Data, new [] {
            new Column<ListEntry> { TDContent = i => i.Id }
        });
    }
}
```

What I'm wondering is why "new Column< ListEntry > { ... }" has to specify an explicit type. I'd really rather have it just be ""new Column { ... }" and have the type inferred as ListEntry.

Comment: `A<T>` and `A` are different types... Could you please [edit] question to clarify if you are looking for reasons why C# allows generic and non-generic classes to have the same name or why not automatically infer type when there is no (yet) ambiguous choice between `A<T>` and `A` when you call `new A ()`.

Comment: Not what you have asked... but... Would not it be more readable and clear for the consumers to use Builder pattern instead of doing this kind of raw initialization?
Something like `BasicTable().SetSource(Data).AddColumn(...).AddColumn(...).Render()`

Comment: C# doesn't have generic type inferance for constructors is the simple answer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45604/why-doesnt-c-sharp-support-implied-generic-types-on-class-constructors